# C language: read in hex from file to populate array

Tags: c, hex, fgets

I am currently making an encryption/decryption program. After encryption, the result is stored in a text file, with each character stored as a hex value. 
I am currently working on the decryption, and the first stage is to read in that file, and store each hex value as an element in an array.

```
FILE * decryptIn = fopen("output.txt", "r");
fseek(decryptIn, 0L, SEEK_END); //counts the amount of bytes from start to end of file
int fileSize = ftell(decryptIn); //stores the size of the file in bytes
rewind(decryptIn); //sets offset back to 0 (back to start of file)

int *decryptHexArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*5*fileSize);
int currentPointer;
int counter = 0;

while(fgets(decryptHexArray[counter], fileSize, decryptIn)) //loop that reads each string from the file
{
    counter++;
}
```

The error message I am getting is

> passing argument 1 of 'fgets' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast

Is it possible to achieve what i want with fgets?

Comment: well with hex you can also have `A` so i think its better to just use a `char` array

Comment: Consult this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693841/read-contents-of-a-file-as-hex-in-c ; you'll need `strtoul` http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul

Comment: How are the hexdecimal values delimited? Can you assume whitespace-separation? Is there a leading `0x` before each number?

Answer (score 3):

`char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n,FILE * restrict stream);` But you are passing an `int` to it.. that's why the complain. It even says that it is 
considering the passed `int` type as `char*` but there is no explicit casting provided. So it raised the warning.

You can read the number in a char array first then use `strto*` to get the converted `int`.