# issue in file handling in c

Tags: c, file-handling, uint8t

Hi i am trying to read two characters from a file and want to send it to uint8_t* as hexadecimal .
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int file_handling();

int main() 
{
   uint8_t *output ;

   output=file_handling() ;

   printf("\noutput_main -->  %02x",output);

}

int file_handling()
{ 
    uint8_t *output_hand ;

    char c;

    FILE *f_gets = fopen("filename", "r");
    if(f_gets==NULL)
    {
       printf("Please point to a valid key file!\n");
       fclose(f_gets);  
       return 0;
    }
    char str[3];

    if( fgets (str, 3, f_gets)!=NULL ) 
    {
     /* writing content to stdout */
      puts(str);
      output_hand = (uint8_t *)(str); 
      puts(output_hand);    
      printf("\noutput %s --- %02x --> size --> %lu",str,*output_hand,sizeof(*output_hand));
    }
    fclose(f_gets);

    return *output_hand;
}
```

following is output

```
we we

output we --- 77 --> size --> 1 output_main -->  65
```

what i can understand is 77 is ascii for w and 65 is ascii for e

but i want to put "we" which i suppose is a hex in uint8_t *output 
where is the problem
in main ,if i use pointer "*output=file_handling()" instead of just output i get segmentation fault.

How to read value from a file and put it into  uint8_t , where file is having hex characters,how fget identifies it as hex or char.

Thanks

file is a text file

```
ab
fe
ea
ce
1d
```

Basically 
uint8_t *output;
*output = 0xFA ;
it works 
but i want to read from above file and put it into output variable

Comment: There is a lot that is wrong (probably half a dozen things or so) with the code you have written Sam.  Perhaps it would be better to show us an example of what is in the file and what you would like your output to be and then we can work from there.

Comment: the file contains hex characters

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  Are you just trying to read data from a file and print it to the screen?  Are you trying to manipulate the data in some way?  If you simply want to print the character rather than the decimal value of it, use `%c` instead of `%s` (which, btw, was wrong to begin with because of a host of other issues some of which are pointed out by Some programmer dude).

Comment: @jszakmeister the file contains just characters ,  i want to read them and put it into uint8_t *output as hex values ,first thing i don't know how to print uint8_t,secondly unint8_t will contain 1 byte of hex characters that is two char , so i am tring to read two characters from the file at a time .

Comment: "but i want to put "we" which i suppose is a hex"  What is "a hex"? It is a two letter string. If you want to convert from ASCII to integer, then consult your beginner-level C programming book.

Comment: The line `output=file_handling() ;` will not even compile on a C compiler.

Comment: @Lundin How to read characters from file and put it uint8_t ?

Comment: @Lundin I am using gcc on ubuntu and its getting compiled

Comment: You need to tell gcc to be a C compiler instead of a Gnu crapiler. This is done by `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wall`. As for how to convert from ASCII to integer, do some research and check the hundreds of SO threads already present on that topic.

Comment: Try making this into a [mcve], please! <3

Comment: I got answer on following page first solution :) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693841/read-contents-of-a-file-as-hex-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693841/read-contents-of-a-file-as-hex-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You have plenty of problems, here's three of them:

- You define `str` to be an array of two characters, which means it can only contain a single-character string. You then call `fgets` telling it that `str` it *three* characters, which means it can and will write out of bounds of your array.
- You have declared `file_handling` to return an `int` value. You return the first character in the array `string`, and assign that to the *pointer* variable `output` in the `main` function. You then treat this *pointer* as a single `int` value.
- In the `main` function you pass the *pointer* `output` but print it as an `int` value. There's a mismatch between the format specifier and the argument.

The first and third issues lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).